# Why PHP cURL is not setting the cookie?

Tags: php, curl, cookies

I'm processing two consequent requests the first one is login and this request set the login session cookie.

The second request is a regular request and I expect that cookies from the first request was already set.

The problem is that cookies are not set by cURL at the first request although the remote server sent the set-cookie header back

Here is the verbose result processing the first request

```
> POST /account/login HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.8) Gecko/2009032609 Firefox/3.0.8
Host: forwp.accounts.clickbank.com
Accept: */*
Referer: http://www.bing.com/
Content-Length: 90
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

* upload completely sent off: 90 out of 90 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Date: Mon, 26 Oct 2015 12:03:17 GMT
* Server Apache is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache
< SET-COOKIE: token=Zm9yd3A6MTQ0NTg5Njk5NzkxOTowMzFhZWQzM2NmYzk0YmQ5MDY0YjEyMzQzOWU1NmZmMQ; Path=/; Domain=forwp.accounts.clickbank.com; Secure; HttpOnly;
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=72878AC21A7658ADC34514BB1CD9A936.AW1; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
< Location: https://forwp.accounts.clickbank.com/account/mainMenu.htm
< Content-Length: 0
```

Running the same request at my local PC, It sets the cookie without any issues.

```
* upload completely sent off: 124 out of 124 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Date: Mon, 26 Oct 2015 12:04:45 GMT
* Server Apache is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache
* Added cookie token="c3dlZXRoZWF0bToxNDQ1ODk3MDg1OTQ2OjRjNjhmMGMzODIzZmJmOTVhNWYzMzMxNzUyNmY4NWY4" for domain sweetheatm.accounts.clickbank.com, path /, expire 0
< SET-COOKIE: token=c3dlZXRoZWF0bToxNDQ1ODk3MDg1OTQ2OjRjNjhmMGMzODIzZmJmOTVhNWYzMzMxNzUyNmY4NWY4; Path=/; Domain=sweetheatm.accounts.clickbank.com; Secure; HttpOnly;
* Added cookie JSESSIONID="7E3C5B212D0C1428102A65BDAE57F100.AW1" for domain sweetheatm.accounts.clickbank.com, path /, expire 0
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=7E3C5B212D0C1428102A65BDAE57F100.AW1; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
< Location: https://sweetheatm.accounts.clickbank.com/account/mainMenu.htm
< Content-Length: 0
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: Are you saving the cookies somewhere? Your browser does this automagically, but you need to tell `cURL` explicitly - see e.g. this: http://icfun.blogspot.cz/2009/04/php-how-to-use-cookie-jar-with-curl.html

Can you show the code which makes the first request?

Comment: Sure I have set the CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR  and also using the absolute path and making sure it exists and writable.